# Can't execute command in java

Tags: java, cmd

I want one of these commands to be executed. I can't do it in java.
Commands are:

```
type table1.sql, table2.sql, table3.sql > sBackup.sql
type *.sql > allinone.sql  --[Make a backup for all file in the folder]
copy *.sql merged.sql
```

I tried this:

```
String command = "type " + "*.sql" + " --result-file=" + "c:\\sBackup.sql";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Your valuable insight is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: That's not *executing* an sql command. That's typing out a file.

Answer (score 2):

`type` and `copy` are both built-ins in the Windows command shell, not actual programs you can execute. To execute them, you execute a command shell and provide the command as an argument after a `/C`:

```
String command = "cmd.exe /C type " + "*.sql" + " --result-file=" + "c:\\sBackup.sql";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

---

...but I'll just note that I don't think `type` has a `--result-file` argument.

Comment: Output can simply be redirected to a new file using `>` I guess, there is no such `--result-file` attribute for `type` command I think!